# Using a Wii classic controller with Xbox

Tags: controllers, nintendo-wii, xbox

I just ordered an original Xbox and a controller. However, I also have a Wii classic controller pro that I don't use anymore. I am wondering if there is some way for me to connect my Wii controller to the Xbox for use as a second controller. I googled it and found nothing, so I was wondering if anybody here knew of a way to do it.

Comment: You found nothing, because it's not possible.  Why would a peripheral ever connect to a console its manufacturer competes with?

Comment: Well, I did find an adapter to use it with a ps3, so I know that it is probably possible. I am not looking for a direct connection, I am thinking more of an adapter with components on the inside to make the transition. I know that it doesn't directly connect.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible way to connect a Wii controller to an XBOX. It would be quite a hassle to play certain games, such as Halo, and not be able to play it due to the fact that the Wiimote (Wii Remote) does not have 2 functional joysticks, X and Y buttons, or a multitude of other buttons. If you want two different controllers, you should probably just order another one.

Comment: He's not asking about connecting a Wiimote, he's asking about connecting a Wii [Classic Controller Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Controller#Classic_Controller_Pro).  Which looks suspiciously like a PS2 controller.

Comment: Ah. Well, no matter what Nintendo controller he desires to connect, it **will not work**. The only compatible controller to the XBOX is the XBOX controller.

Comment: Since the Xbox 360 uses a modified version of XInput (which Windows also uses), I wouldn't be so sure of that.

Comment: This is for an original xbox, not a 360. DekuLeaf is probably right, I just wanted to see if I had missed something when I searched for a way to do this.

Comment: I'll Probably just sell or trade in the wii classic controller and buy an xbox controller. Even if there was a way, I wouldn't have pressure sensitive triggers, l/r 3 buttons, or the black/white buttons.